# Перенаправление вывода в переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Доброго времени суток. Есть вот такая проблема: надо вывод консоли считать в переменную. Мне нужно считать то, что выводит в консоль программа `ffprobe.exe`. Нашел вот такой способ:

```
text = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe.exe -i "Sad But True.mp3"'],encoding="cp866")
```

Программа выполняется, выводит в консоль текст, а в переменную записывается пустая строка. При этом если использовать то же самое для команды `ipconfig`, например, то все сработает как надо. Может кто-нибудь знает почему так?

P.S. Другим способом я эту задачу решил, но хотелось бы знать что не так с тем вариантом. Сейчас использую такой способ:

```
command = input()
text =subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
text = text.stdout.read().decode('cp866')
```

Comment: судя по всему `ffprobe.exe` выводит в STDERR, вместо STDOUT - поэтому второй метод работает... или я не понял суть вопроса?